# PHP Search an Array for maximum key / value pairs

Tags: php, laravel

I have a array list, How can I get with PHP the highest key value pair in an array?

```
   array:4 [
  0 => array:2 [
    "free_shipping" => true
    "coupon_amt" => 20
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    "coupon_amt" => 120
    "free_shipping" => false
  ]
  2 => array:2 [
    "free_shipping" => false
    "coupon_amt" => 100
  ]
  3 => array:2 [
    "coupon_amt" => 200
    "free_shipping" => true
  ]
]
```

Any ideas or suggestions on how I can or should do this?

```
    array:4 [
  0 => array:2 [
    "free_shipping" => true
    "coupon_amt" => 200
  ]
]
```

Comment: An alternative to the solution provided by @Jerodev could be to use [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) with similar logic as the foreach loop. Or you could wrap the array in a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#introduction) and leverage [max](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-max) and [where](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-where) to obtain the same result.

Comment: Does free shipping need to be true?

Comment: What if two pairs both have the highest value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple loop seems the best option to me.

```
$max = null;
foreach ($array as $part) {
    if ($max === null || $part['coupon_amt'] > $max['coupon_amt']) {
        $max = $part;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you try this:

**First Convert the array to collection**

```
$collection = collect($array);
```

**And then sort it**

```
$sorted = $collection->sortByDesc('coupon_amt');
```

**then if you want it to be array again just do this**

```
$array = $sorted->toArray();
```

**then just get the first array**

```
$first = $array[0];
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Use the [collections'](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#introduction) available methods such as [max](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-max) and [where](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-where).

```
<?php

$collection = collect($array);

print_r($collection->where('coupon_amt',$collection->max('coupon_amt'))->all());
```

Comment: That's a big overhead for such a simple task.

Comment: @Jerodev How come? Since the OP has tag of `Laravel`, I suggested collections method.

Comment: The solution will indeed work perfectly, no argument there. But you are creating an extra object and looping over the entire array at least twice. :)

Comment: @Jerodev Yes, of course it is less efficient, but this overhead is negligible.

Answer (score 0):

$collection = collect($array);

print_r($collection->where('coupon_amt',$collection->max('coupon_amt'))->all());